# Powershell csv files and conditional statements

Tags: powershell, csv

I am relatively new to scripting and have been trying to solve a particular script problem in powershell,
I am having difficult in exporting the output to a csv file, the script runs fine when displaying to the console but i either get string lengths or content relaring to the script. I am missing something with changing properties to content but cant seem to workout how to do it
Many thanks in anticipation

```
import-csv "C:\scripts\test1\data-Raw.csv"|
foreach{ 
if ($_.Hide -eq 'True') { @{OutFinal=$_.OT_Pre,$_.extension}}
if ($_.Hide -eq 'False') { @{OutFinal=$_.extension,$_.extension}}
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\scripts\test1\data-2.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

try to convert in pscustomobject like this

```
import-csv "C:\scripts\test1\data-Raw.csv"|
foreach{ 
if ($_.Hide -eq 'True') { [pscustomobject]@{OutFinal=$_.OT_Pre;Extension=$_.extension}}
else { [pscustomobject]@{OutFinal=$_.extension;Extension=$_.extension}}
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\scripts\test1\data-2.csv"
```

or simply like it:

```
import-csv "C:\scripts\test1\data-Raw.csv"|
foreach{
    [pscustomobject]@{
    OutFinal=if ($_.Hide -eq 'True'){$_.OT_Pre} else {$_.extension}
    Extension=$_.extension
    } 
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\scripts\test1\data-2.csv"
```

if you want keep all property and add property you can do like it:

```
import-csv "C:\scripts\test1\data-Raw.csv"|
    select *, @{Name="OutFinal"; Expression={if ($_.Hide -eq 'True'){$_.OT_Pre} else {$_.extension}}} |
        Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "C:\scripts\test1\data-2.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks the first soltion seems to overcome my issue as a sidenote how would i include the other fields in the source csv file to the output i have tried combinations of $_. etc but i feel i dont fully understand this component in scripting yet